# Some apps on my Macbook Pro cannot be uninstalled

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, ios, macos-sonoma

I just bought Macbook Pro 2019 16/256 and I've installed a bunch of apps in a few days then I've realized one app, "Google Keep notes and list", suddenly installed and I want to uninstall it but can't, it also cannot be open.

I've tried to drag it to trash bin, remove it from applications folder but it doesn't appear, tried to remove it from the library folder but it's also not there.

[image: macomaco]

Comment: If in Finder you click Applications, do you see in the programs list an entry for "Google Keep for Desktop", and can you drag the app's icon to the Trash to remove it?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the application?

Comment: What other Google products did you/are installed on this MacBook? It's possible the app you're trying to remove is a pointer or shortcut of some sort, or it was "pushed" by another Google app trying to be "helpful". These are mostly guesses on my part, but I find this behavior consistent with how Google behaves in general.

Comment: the app cannot be drag to the Trash, i want to delete the apps since it cannot be open and it has weird name "Google keep... tes and lists" and i only installed chrome